# Regarding Regex in java

Tags: java, regex

I have a string as below.

```
   $x:Test( (x==5 || y==4) && ( (r==9 || t==10) && ( n>=2 || t<=4))) demo program
```

In the above string the number of left and right paranthesis's will be changed based on the condition.

My requirement is whenever i encounter last right paranthesis then need to concatenate the below string.

```
 from "stream"
```

So the result will be as below.

```
$x:Test( (x==5 || y==4) && ( (r==9 || t==10) && ( n>=2 || t<=4))) from "stream" demo program
```

To achieve this i am trying with the following code in java.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*?\\.Event\\(([^\\(]*?|\\([^\\)]*?\\))*\\)");

if(line.matches(".*\\.Test(.*).*")){
    line = pattern.matcher(line).replaceAll("$0 from  \""+"stream"+"\""+" ");                 
}
```

But the above code is not working if the number of left and right paranthesis are more than 5 .

Need pointers to acheive the desired result i mean i need generic solution for any number of left and right parantheses.

Answer (score 5):

Why would you like to do it with Regex? Just use simple `String` class methods - [`String#lastIndexOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf%28int%29) and [`String#substring`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) to approach the problem: -

```
String str = "$x:Test( (x==5 || y==4) && ( (r==9 || t==10) && " + 
             "( n>=2 || t<=4))) demo program";

int index = str.lastIndexOf(")");
str = str.substring(0, index + 1) + " from \"stream\"" + 
      str.substring(index + 1);
```

`Regexp` is a very powerful language, but is really not required for something like this, where you are sure that where you need to split your string.

Comment: you are right but the problem is that there might be chance of having two three substrings like $x:Test( (x==5 || y==4) && ( (r==9 || t==10) && " + 
             "( n>=2 || t<=4))) demo program"                       and                                                         $x:Sample( (x==5 || y==4) && ( (r==9 || t==10) && " + 
             "( n>=2 || t<=4))) demo program .In this case i need to add the string  "from stream" to both $x:Test(****) and $x:Sample(****).That is the reason i am using the regex.

Comment: @user1668653. This is exactly not what your original question says. Please post all the possible input and output you expect there.

Comment: @user1668653. And if you are having that kind of situation, then also `Regex` is not what you want. `Regex` is not very good at matching `opening and closing` brackets.

Answer (score 1):

To get it after the rightmost parantheses, you can just use `replaceFirst()` like this:

```
String data = "   $x:Test( (x==5 || y==4) && ( (r==9 || t==10) && ( n>=2 || t<=4))) demo program ";
data = data.replaceFirst("^(.*\\))([^)]*)$", "$1 from \"stream\"$2");
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use [String.lastIndexOf()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf%28int%29) ?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use `lastIndexOf()` and `substring()` functions as below:

```
String text = 
  "$x:Test( (x==5 || y==4) && ( (r==9 || t==10) && ( n>=2 || t<=4))) demo program";

int lastIndex = text.lastIndexOf(")");
String updatedText = 
        text.substring(0,lastIndex)+" from \"stream\""+text.substring(lastIndex+1);
```

**EDIT:** use `replaceAll` to replace all occurrences of `)))` with `))) from "stream"` as below:

```
 String text = 
  "$x:Test( (x==5 || y==4) && ( (r==9 || t==10) && ( n>=2 || t<=4))) demo program";

 String updatedText = text.replaceAll("\\)\\)\\)", "\\)\\)\\) from \"stream\"");
```

Comment: the problem is that there might be chance of having two three substrings like $x:Test( (x==5 || y==4) && ( (r==9 || t==10) && " + "( n>=2 || t<=4))) demo program" and $x:Sample( (x==5 || y==4) && ( (r==9 || t==10) && " + "( n>=2 || t<=4))) demo program .In this case i need to add the string "from stream" to both $x:Test(*) and $x:Sample(*).That is the reason i am using the regex

Comment: @user1668653 Do you mean, in same string, you may have more instance of  `)))` and you would like to replace `)))` with `))) from "Stream"`?

Answer (score 0):

The .* is greedy in Regex, thus search for `^(.*\))(.*)` and replace with `$1 from \"stream\"$2`.